# YouTube Data API v3 のバグ?

Tags: youtube-data-api

YouTube Data API v3で次のリクエストを取得し､`nextPageToken`を使って､次のページのデータを取得するのですが､しばらく繰り返すと同じデータを返すようになります｡ また､すべての結果を合計しても`totalResults`より少ない数の結果しか受け取れません｡ これはバグでしょうか?

**URL:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=%e6%8a%80%e9%80%a3%0d%0a&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&order=viewCount&type=video&videoDefinition=high&publishedAfter=2015-01-14T08:44:36.46Z&key={APIKEY}
```

このURLあたりから､同じ結果を返すようになります｡

**ループが始まるURL**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search&pageToken=CGQQAA&q=%E6%8A%80%E9%80%A3%0d%0a&part=id,snippet&maxResults=20&order=viewCount&type=video&videoDefinition=high&publishedAfter=2015-01-14T08:44:36.46Z&key={APIKEY}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Issue 4282 - gdata-issues - Youtube API V3 & V2: Impossible to get ALL 1000 results on a search - Server-side issues and feature requests - Google Project Hosting](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4282#c24)

> We can't provide more than ~500 search results for any arbitrary YouTube query via the API without the quality of the search results severely degrading (duplicates, etc.).
>
> The v1/v2 GData API was updated back in November to limit the number of search results returned to 500. If you specify a start-index of 500 or more, you won't get back any results.
>
> This was supposed to have also gone into effect for the v3 API (which uses a different method of paging through results) but it apparently was not pushed out, so it is still possible to retrieve up to 1000 search results in v3—the last 500 of which are usually of bad quality.
>
> The change to limit v3 to 500 search results will be pushed out sometime in the near future. There will no longer be nextPageTokens returned once you hit 500 results.
>
> I understand that the totalResults that are returned is much higher than 500 in all of these cases, but that is not the same thing as saying that we can effectively return all X million possible results. It's meant as an estimate of the total size of the set of videos that match a query and normally isn't very useful.

- 重複などのない結果を返せるのは今のところ500件まで
- v1/v2は500件までしか取得できないように仕様変更した
- v3は今のところ1000件まで取得できるが、代わりに後半500件の品質はいまひとつ
- 将来的にv3も500件に制限される予定

というところのようです。